# Shell Script -directory compare- output

Tags: bash, shell

I compare two directories with:

```
diff --brief -s dir1/ dir2/
```

That works fine and i got the following output:

```
Only in dir1/: test1
Files dir1/test2 and dir2/test2 differ
Only in dir2/: test3
Files dir1/test4 and dir2/test4 are identical
```

Is it possible to get an output of the listed files test1...test4 like `ls -l dir1/` does?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you are trying to do? the question is hard to understand

Comment: What I understand: You have a list of files (from your diff or wherever) and call `ls -l` on them. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Sorry for bad description. I fixed it and added more information.

Comment: How exactly do you want your output to look like? Can you write an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an awk script to do it for you, like

```
diff --brief -s dir1/ dir2/ | awk '
    /^Only in/ { system("ls -l " gensub(":$","","1",$3) $4) }
    /^Files/ { system("ls -l " $2 " " $4) }'
```

But that gives the same results (in wrong order) as `ls -l dir1/ dir2/`... (because diff outputs every file. So you might want to respecify your requirements. (And show us what have you tried yet...)